# MKMapView userlocation difference

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Declaration;)

> MKMapView mapView;

I can't found the difference between mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate and mapView.userLocation.coordinate. Is there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapView.userLocation return an MKUserLocation ([here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/userLocation)) and I don't know where you have found this, but it has no member call coordinate.
(see [MKUserLocation Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserLocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKUserLocation))

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep to post this as a comment on Yannick's answer so I have to post as a separate answer.

**MKUserLocation** conforms to **MKAnnotation**.  **MKAnnotation** has a required *coordinate* property, so this should work:

```
mapView.userLocation.coordinate
```

That said, I don't know if it differs from mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.  I can't imagine that it does.